# how to remove decimal and thousand separater in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert and display `4.520` to `4520` or `5.000` to `5000` in crystal report and concatenate `zz` at start and end so final string should be `zz4520zz` or `zz5000zz`. I am getting number from sql and data is stored in varchar. how can I do this?

```vb
totext(tonumber({DataTable1.number}),0)
```

Comment: Are you saying that the numbers are stored as text in the database? Presumably you know that is not a good thing. Is there a chance of putting the data into a column of the appropriate type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"zz" + totext(tonumber({DataTable1.number}),0,"") + "zz"
```